# change an img using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making the game noughts and crosses and I can't find how to change an img when it is clicked.

This is the gamefield:

```
<div id="playfield">
    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td><img alt="" title="" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
            <td><img alt="" title="" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
            <td><img alt="" title="" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img alt="" title="" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
            <td><img alt="" title="" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
            <td><img alt="" title="" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img alt="" title="" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
            <td><img alt="" title="" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
            <td><img alt="" title="" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

This is the function that picks the player who can start:

```
var randomStart = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
```

and this is the query code for the startgame button:

```
$("#playfield tr td").click(function() {
    if ($(".game-button").html() == "Start game") {
        alert("you are not allowed to start");
    } else {
        if(randomStart == 0){

        } else {

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: where is ".game-button" html"

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Can you prepare JSBin with the failing scenario?

Comment: Are looking for `$(this).find('img').prop('src', newSrcPath)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change an img when it's clicked, you can do it this way:

With the `#playfield img` selector, you have access to all the img of your table. Then `$(this)` will allow you to change your img that's been clicked with the img of your choice with the `attr` function.

```js
var randomStart = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);

$("#playfield img").click(function() {
  $(this).attr('src', 'https://static.skyminds.net/jquery.png');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="playfield">
  <table border="0">
    <tr>
      <td><img alt="" title="" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
      <td><img alt="" title="" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img alt="" title="" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
      <td><img alt="" title="" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img alt="" title="" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
      <td><img alt="" title="" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: OP wouldn't want to set the same image on every click

Comment: @elementzero23 well, he didn't ask for that

Comment: "I am making the game noughts and crosses"

Comment: @elementzero23 You're right :) I'm not a native speaker so I missed that point.

Answer (score 0):

Add IDs to your images:

```
<img id="image1" alt="" title="" src="img/empty.jpg" />
```

Then you can change the image when clicked like

```
$("#image1").click(function () {
    $(this).prop("src", "img/image-that-should-appear.jpg");
});
```

Surely you can do this without IDs but you probably want to know what image was clicked. You can also achieve this (for example) by using the data attribute:

```
<img alt="" title="" src="img/empty.jpg" data-img-number="1" />
```

And then do

```
$("#playfield img").click(function() {
    var img_number = $(this).data("img-number");
    // change the image based on that information
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work in your case:

```
$('#playfield tr td').click(function() {
    newImageSrc = 'img/newImage.png';
    $(this).children().attr('src', newImageSrc);
})
```